# Mobile PC Remote

Tags: mobile, symbian

If I buy a symbian(S60, [nokia E51](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_e51-2106.php)) mobile, and I want to write a program to control the PC(launch programs, control mouse/keyboard):

1. Is it possible to make a mobile app and a windows app which
   communicates via WiFi, or its easier/faster via bluetooth?
2. Which framework should I choose? (symbian/java)
3. (other info that I might need)

Comment: It's easier to write WiFi programs; Bluetooth is very likely to work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth using native Symbian, and I expect using Qt too. I don't know about Java.

As an example, [ControlFreak](http://mtvoid.com) is an application for older S60 1st and 2nd edition phones (but not 3rd edition, like the E51) to control Winamp and the rest of your computer using Bluetooth.

Head over to [Nokia Developer](http://www.developer.nokia.com/) for SDKs, APIs and forums to ask more questions.